# my jotform is not emailing every form submission

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, jotform

I am new to website development and managment and have been faced with a problem that I am unsure how to answer.

I have a jotform on my website where users can submit warranty claims. Some of our larger customers, may need to submit mulitple warranty claims at a time. The form does not allow for duplicate submissions, but it should allow for people to submit multiple forms, as long as they are unique.

The issue at hand is that when our larger customers need to submit multiple claims, some are being sent to our warranty email, but others are not. That being said, our customers are receiving confirmation emails for every form submission, regardless if we recieving the form or not.

I tried taking out the "submission limit" portion, hoping it would allow for people to submit multiple forms. Although, the only thing that helped with was getting spam emails.

Here is the jotform js: <script type= **[https://form.jotform.com/jsform/231993320631049**"](https://form.jotform.com/jsform/231993320631049**%22)

Please let me know what other kind of information I need to provide in order to help resolve this issue.

Comment: Copy and past the link into the browser, otherwise it won't pull up the right stuff

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

If your website has wordpress then i suggest you to use elementor pro for filling out forms.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).